# Pertinent questions description in the tour - obscure term

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The term "loyalty programme" used in the list of pertinent questions is somewhat obscure; or rather, only used in some countries rather than in others (including the secondary-language English of various companies and government authorities).

I suggest either this be changed to "loyalty/frequent flyer programs", or a link to the [Wikipedia page for loyalty programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalty_program) be added.

Comment: [This help page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) uses the same term but clarifies: " loyalty programmes: frequent flyer points and hotel advantages "

Comment: A newbie going through the tour would probably not figure out s/he needs to get to that page for the explanation.

Comment: yes, I know, that was just as an addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never crossed my mind that this might be considered an obscure term. I've changed it to

> ...frequent flyer or other loyalty/rewards programmes...

which should cover more bases and also provide some context for the completely unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider an external link appropriate as part of the Tour and see little need for the change proposed (anyone in doubt should just be able to arrive at the Wikipedia page on their own - SE expects *some* research from users) but it would seem to be a relatively simple adjustment and would not distort the formatting, so consider it a shame this has not yet been implemented (or any reason provided why not) even though we are an English site and cannot be expected to be fully and immediately intelligible to all for whom English is not their first language or who use variants thereof.

Comment: 1. In the bottom line you agree with me, perhaps you could emphasize that part? :-)  2. Suppose I took the tour once, noticed this term, it was not relevant to what I wanted to ask, so I just forgot about it over time. Later I had a question about frequent flyer miles and did not think that maybe "loyalty programmes" are about the same thing.